# Error in PHP $date2 = $date1->format('Y-m-d')

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function format() on a non-object

in code:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date1 = $date->modify('-6 months');
$date2 = $date1->format('Y-m-d');
```

I want to get this date of 6 months before from now and delete all entries in database which are earlier than this 6 months date:

```
$query = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM files WHERE files.date < ?");
$query->bind_param('s', $date2);
$query->execute();
```

In MySQL "date" field is in files table of datatype "timestamp" whose value is "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" stored by MySQL as default when a row is created.

Comment: Check the type of `$date1`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Can you explain more? I am new to PHP.

Comment: $date1 should be a DateTime object, because that's what the modify() method returns

Comment: Which PHP version are you running? Because docs are saying: `5.3.0 Changed the return value on success from NULL to DateTime.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code get you 6 month ago from now:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now -6 month'))
```

EDIT:

and use DateTime:

```
echo (new DateTime('-6 months'))->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: If OP is using DateTime objects, suggesting that they regress to using basic date functions isn't really the best answer to their problem

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('-6 months');
echo $date2 = $date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the call to

```
$date->modify('-6 months');
```

encounters an error and does not return a `DateTime` instance but probably `false` (see [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.modify.php)).

Which PHP version are you using? I could not reproduce that error with the given example on PHP 5.5.9

Maybe you could just use the [strtotime function](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php)

**EDIT:**

I took the [Wayback Machine from Internet Archive](http://archive.org/web/web.php) and found that older versions of PHP ( i.e. 5.1.0) returned NULL instead of the DateTime object: [see for yourself](http://web.archive.org/web/20080702213244/http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-modify.php). In that case it seems like you apply the modification on your date directly so you need to change your code to

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify('-6 months');
$dateString = $date->format('Y-m-d');

$query = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM files WHERE files.date < ?");
$query->bind_param('s', $dateString);
$query->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using an outdated version of php.

Starting with php 5.3+ `DateTime::modify` returns the datetime object is was called upon prior to that `null` was returned.

You don't need to assign the result of modify to a new variable as it modifies the current object and does not return a new one.

To make it work on 5.2:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify('-6 months');
$dateS = $date->format('Y-m-d');

var_dump($dateS);
```

You should however update your php to a supported version.

PHP 5.4+ short-example:

```
$dateS = (new DateTime('-6 months'))->format('Y-m-d');
```